# How would one solve this system of differential equations for muzzle velocity as a function of initial pressure?

Tags: mathematical-physics, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve for the exit velocity of a projectile of mass *m* from a t-shirt cannon with pressurized air tank with initial pressure $P_0$ but I am stuck on how to solve either analytically or numerically and where to approach. I am following this [paper](http://persweb.wabash.edu/facstaff/madsenm/publications/AJP_80_24_rohrbach_air_cannon.pdf) and understand their method but I can not get through the math.

The schematic of my cannon is shown below.
[image: T-shirt cannon schematic]
The equation of motion of the projectile is:
$$F = m\frac{dx^2}{d^2t} = mv\frac{dv}{dx} = AP(x)-AP_{atm} - F_f$$ where *F* is force, *m* is mass, *v* is velocity, *A* is area, $P(x)$ is pressure as a function of *x* distance and $F_f$ is frictional force (constant). Originally, an adiabatic assumption $P(x)V(x)^\gamma =P_0V_0^\gamma$ and an isothermal assumption $P(x)V(x) =P_0V_0$ were made but since these aren't accurate to the design, a new model had to be determined.

Taking the flow through the valve as a function of valve geometry and pressure differential at time *t*: $$r= \frac{P(t)-P_b(t)}{P(t)}$$ where $P(t)$ and $P_b(t)$ are the pressures in the tank and barrel at time t. When the
pressure difference is large enough, this ratio saturates to $r \to r_{max}$, which is limited by the geometry of the valve and is typically between 0.2 and 0.9. There are thus two flow regimes. In the nonchoked regime where $r < r_{max}$, or equivalently $P(t) < P_b(t)/(1-r_{max})$, the flow is modeled empirically as a function of the pressure differential between the tank
pressure and the barrel pressure: $$Q = BP(t)C_v(1-\frac{r}{3r_{max}})\sqrt{\frac{r}{G_gTZ}}$$
In the choked regime, $P(t) > P_b(t)/(1-r_{max})$, the flow is limited by the geometry of the valve: $$Q = \frac23BP(t)C_v\sqrt{\frac{r_{max}}{G_gTZ}}$$
$G_g = 1$ is the specific gravity of air, $T = 293 K$ is the temperature in the tank which is assumed to be constant, and $Z = 1$ is the compressibility factor. The flow coefficient $C_v$ of the valve is a dimensionless parameter which describes the flow capacity of the valve. The final parameter $B = 3.11 * 10^{19} \frac{\sqrt{K}}{(Pa * s)}$ is an engineering constant which converts the quantity into units of molecules per time.
We model the gas expansion in the barrel and the tank using the ideal gas law:
$$P(t)V_0 = N(t)k_bT$$
$$P_b(t)A(d+x(t)) = N_b(t)k_bT$$
where $N$ and $N_b$ are the number of molecules in the tank and barrel, respectively. The number of molecules in the tank and barrel are governed by the flow of molecules between them through the valve:
$$\frac{dN}{dt} = -Q$$
$$\frac{dN_b}{dt} = Q$$
Using these equations and combining with initial conditions can be solved for: $$v = \frac{dx}{dt}\bigg|_{x=L}$$
where initial conditions are $P(0) = P_0$, $P_b(0) = P_{atm}$, $x(0) = 0$, $N(0) = \frac{P_0V_0}{k_bT}$, $N_b(0) = \frac{P_{atm}Ad}{k_bT}$.

How did they solve these equations for v if everything is in terms of time while the equation of motion is in terms of distance?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use equation $(1)$ for the $x$ position of the plug since the distance $L$ doesn't change, and solve the other equations with the initial conditions as inputs to equation $(1)$. And if you get stuck, try contacting the authors.